# [Q]Select property from object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am learning TypeScript in React and I have a problem with accessing property via a method argument.

```
    const [product, setProduct] = useState("electricity");
        const defaultProps = {
        price: {
              electricity: 0.51,
              gas: 4.7,
              oranges: 3.79,
            },
          };
 const selectPrice = (select: any) => {
    console.log(defaultProps.price[select]);
  };
        const handleSelect = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        setProduct(e.target.value);
      };
        <Cash
                price={selectPrice(product)}
              />
    
    <select value={product} onChange={handleSelect}>
              <option value="electricity">electricity</option>
              <option value="gas">gas</option>
              <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
            </select>
```

Problem is in selectPrice method.
I have the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ electricity: number; gas: number; oranges: number; }'.ts(7053)".
I don't know how I can get access to the property of object price in object defaultProps.
In guide teacher is using the javascript and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a type of the possible options of the select.

```
const selectPrice = (select: 'electricity'| 'gas' | 'oranges') => {
  console.log(defaultProps.price[select]);
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and select the answer

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed once you change `select: any` to `select: string`. Since `price` can be indexed only using strings, when you set `select: any` there is a possibility that select could be a `number`, `boolean` or some other type, which will cause a runtime error, which is why Typescript is complaining.

Since the benefit of using Typescript over Javascript is the stronger typing system, you should avoid using `any` whenever possible to take advantage of Typescript's ability to catch runtime bugs caused by mismatched types

Comment: I tried with string and it did not work. Gordon's solution is working perfect